# Django, how to call a query whenever user logs in?

Tags: django, loginview, django-login

I am creating an application in Django. I have a model called `Business_profile` having `User` as foreign key. Now what I want is every time a user logs in the application, i want to display following hyper links in the base template:

1) If entry in Business_profile exists :

Show links:

- HOME
- BUSINESS PAGE

2) If entry in Business_profile does not exist:

- HOME
- ADD BUSINESS

Now I know query would be `Business_profile.objects.filter(user=user_obj).exists()`

But I want to check this when the user logs in, how to do this? Is there a way to override login view? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides a signal `user_logged_in` whenever a user logs in. You could register to listen to that signal and do your stuff when you get the signal.

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def do_my_stuff(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    whatever actions you want to to go here

user_logged_in.connect(do_my_stuff)
```

Comment: i have got this thing somewhere but not sure where to write this code, if you could please provide me with something

Comment: @ D.S. Dhaliwal, `django.auth` is sending the `user_logged_in`. You have to write the `do_my_stuff` function. This is the receiver function. The line `user_logged_in.connect(do_my_stuff)` is basically connecting the receiver (your function) to the sender (django.auth). You can put this anywhere you like, usually the place where you are doing most of your processing work. Your app’s models.py is uaually a good place to put this or if your app is the type where everything is processed in views.py, then you could put it there.

Answer (score 0):

This is really very easy in django with its authorization feature look at the following link:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14.html?

```
    if 'password' in request.POST and 'username' in request.POST:
         user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        auth.login(request,user)
        #do your queries here
        return render(request,'htmlpage.html',{'data':data}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that sure about the thing your up to but here's what your question makes me guess.

If you point the user to a login page both with a direct link or through a `@login_required` decorator on a view, you can have her redirected to the URL set in your settings file under `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` or the one in the `next` parameter in your POST request (which takes precedence).

That said, what takes place after the POST submission is a GET request for the page under one of these URL. If your Business_profile model depends on the user being authenticated I would simply check for user authentication for showing the links HOME and ADD BUSINESS while the user is not authenticated.

When she logs in you should take care of passing your views the Business_profile object to tackle with in the rendered template. But if I correctly understood you shouldn't need to manage this in the login view, it should be arranged for in all the views for which the user has been already authenticated.